# What does れれっ mean?

Tags: slang, interjections

> れれっ？　本当にないっすか？
>   　んー、おっかしいなぁー

It's a conversation from video game, one of the characters is 
surprised by the answer of his companion.

My guess it's something like "Huuuh? Not really? 
Hmmm, strangelyyy"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like an intentionally odd or silly rendering of あれれ？, which is itself a mildly exaggerated version of あれ(っ)？, a normal expression of surprise.

Your guess about this is correct.

The rest of your guess is actually a bit less so - 本当にないっすか is 'is it really not there?', and おかしいなー is closer to 'that's strange' (it's not an adverb).